# move GroupBox position without menubar and tools in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to move the position of `groupbox` in window but `menubar` and `tools` are also moved.

how do I fix it and just move the position of `GroupBox`? (The `move` command does not work)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        V = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry()
        h, w, x, y = V.height(), V.width(), 1000, 600
        self.setGeometry(h/4, w/20, x, y)
        self.setFixedSize(x, y)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        OpenFile = QtWidgets.QAction('Open', self)
        OpenFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        OpenFile.setStatusTip('Open Restore File...')
        self.statusBar()
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(OpenFile)
        self.home()
    def home(self):
        self.tools_in_home()
        self.show()
    def tools_in_home(self):
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test')
        self.groupBox.setFixedSize(800, 400)
        self.setContentsMargins(100, 100, 100, 100) # <=== HERE
        hBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.groupBox.setLayout(hBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.groupBox)
def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        V = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry()
        h, w, x, y = V.height(), V.width(), 1000, 600
        self.setGeometry(h/4, w/20, x, y)
        self.setFixedSize(x, y)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        left, top, right, bottom = 100, 100, 100, 100
        centralWidget.setContentsMargins(left, top, right, bottom)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        OpenFile = QtWidgets.QAction('Open', self)
        OpenFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        OpenFile.setStatusTip('Open Restore File...')
        self.statusBar()
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(OpenFile)
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.tools_in_home()
        self.show()

    def tools_in_home(self):
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test') 
        self.groupBox.setFixedSize(800, 400)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox)


def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

[image]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        V = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry()
        h, w, x, y = V.height(), V.width(), 1000, 670            # 600
        self.setGeometry(h/4, w/20, x, y)
        self.setFixedSize(x, y)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        left, top, right, bottom = 50, 50, 50, 50
        centralWidget.setContentsMargins(left, top, right, bottom)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        OpenFile = QtWidgets.QAction('Open', self)
        OpenFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        OpenFile.setStatusTip('Open Restore File...')
        self.statusBar()
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(OpenFile)
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.tools_in_home()
        self.show()

    def tools_in_home(self):
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test') 
        self.groupBox.setFixedSize(400, 200)            #(800, 400)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0)

# +++ vvvvv        
        self.groupBox1 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 1')
        self.groupBox1.setFixedSize(400, 100)
        self.groupBox2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 2')
        self.groupBox2.setFixedSize(400, 100)
        self.groupBox3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 3')
        self.groupBox3.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox1, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox2, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox3, 2, 1)
# +++ ^^^^^


def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

[image]

Comment: thank's, but what should I do if I want to create four groupbox with different position?

Comment: @Nima  I have added updates on the question that interests you.